# Object literal which implements an interface which in turn uses a generic method

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I have the following custom types and interfaces:

```
export type MultiMedia = 'image' | 'audio' | 'video';
export type FieldType = 'string' | 'number' | 'boolean' | MultiMedia;

export interface Field {
  name: string,
  label: string,
  type: FieldType,
  validator: <T>(val: T) => boolean,
  bounds: { lower: number; upper: number }
}

export interface Theme {
  title: string,
  logoPath: string,
  tags: string[],
  fields: Field[]
}
```

Since field type is different from one to the other, i have defined `validator` as a generic method in `Field` interface. When i want to make an object literal which implements `Field` interface typescript complains

> Type '(val: string) => boolean' is not assignable to type '(val: T) => boolean.

```
const fields: Field[] = [
  {
    name: "firstName",
    label: "First Name",
    type: "string",
    bounds: { lower: 1, upper: 1 },
    validator: (val: string) => {
     return val.length > 20;
    }
  }
```

I can change `Field` interface as follows to solve the problem.

```
export interface Field<T> {
  name: string,
  label: string,
  type: FieldType,
  validator: (val: T) => boolean,
  bounds: { lower: number; upper: number }
}
```

But then typescript complains about `fields` property in `Theme` interface.

> Generic Type 'Field' requires 1 type argument(s).

Comment: If `type` is `"audio"`, what you you want `validator` to accept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue here is that `Field` is fundamentally a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types), since you want it to be *either* a `string` field, *or* a `number` field, etc etc.  The way I'd do this is make a generic `SpecificField<F>` interface that represents the constraint from each field type `F` to its validator, and then make `Field` a type alias to the union of all `SpecificField<F>` types:

First let's define the field mapping so we know what the validator should accept

```
interface FieldMapping {
  image: HTMLImageElement; // guessing
  audio: HTMLAudioElement; // guessing
  video: HTMLVideoElement; // guessing
  string: string;
  number: number;
  boolean: boolean;
}
```

And now the `SpecificField<F>` interface:

```
export interface SpecificField<F extends FieldType> {
  name: string;
  label: string;
  type: F;
  validator: (val: FieldMapping[F]) => boolean;
  bounds: { lower: number; upper: number };
}
```

You can see how `SpecificField<string>` will have `type` of `"string"` and a `validator` that accepts only `string` values.  Then we make `Field` be a union, which can happen like this:

```
type Field = { [F in FieldType]: SpecificField<F> }[FieldType];
```

This uses a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) to get each field as a property and then gets the union by [looking up](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#keyof-and-lookup-types) all the properties.  You can verify that it evaluates to:

```
type Field = SpecificField<"string"> | SpecificField<"number"> |
  SpecificField<"boolean"> | SpecificField<"image"> | SpecificField<"audio"> | 
  SpecificField<"video">
```

Then you can verify that the following works:

```
const fields: Field[] = [
  {
    name: "firstName",
    label: "First Name",
    type: "string",
    bounds: { lower: 1, upper: 1 },
    validator: (val: string) => {
      return val.length > 20;
    }
  }
];
```

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcCyBXANjAlm4AE1wEM4BeOAIlwFsSBzYKuAH2pI2IhfaoDdchYDwDcAKFCRYCZKgBiuYFkIAVORWoBnGFFwA7Br2r6MtAEbAoxquYgQswEvuOYc+IqQniDMKwDMSAGMFJRU0EjAwAwY4AG9xODg6RmAALjgACVU0ABkASXomAFFHWmB9GAkkzm4M7LyAQS5cCFLgcsrquEFhCHqc3IA1IRF2zqrEuB09QwyZmO7TCysM5csobrsHJ30M7cdnCQBfcUlwaHhfAODUAGUUINx-XCDFZUIAHnk4UD99QhaODvFTqFAAPniU30JHK810iymWBIliw8NmDG6SBQGXk3X4JCwQhIMGgGQAFAS0cCwoQIlEYgBteQAXQAlBRIQddlsIBgAVoMnE4FgIAB3VZwdZWURwDBRSXSqBwY4nM7Y0IfTTC5nJfQ0j5g4AsjIPYBPF5vWnfSHHZm0o0s7xSS56vxQQIhOCqAAWHVQCSSeBgjnRiKSooYEAACiSfWHDFjGILpgjDIynVMXh8UyDCBm1eIghB9Do4NmVLnaRnNIypoGklLYelqC8oDoAHLNqgAGimEZRygyVEU7fgXfKvf7shx2jTRj7jbgdn5gKFIvFkoAjD25QqoBktyrF42qcTSQe4JTCQmGBzyJCG0uoMAYBgoPqqQA6RyGGA+uBIQAJgABm6JJTgg8RMyAA)

Comment: This is exactly what i need. Thanks for taking time to provide such a detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your last example will work, except you need to declare the type of `T` when you use the `Field` interface (both in the `Theme` interface declaration and in the constant `fields` declaration), not when `validator` is declared:

```
export type MultiMedia = 'image' | 'audio' | 'video';
export type FieldType = 'string' | 'number' | 'boolean' | MultiMedia;

export interface Field<T> {
  name: string,
  label: string,
  type: FieldType,
  validator: (val: T) => boolean,
  bounds: { lower: number; upper: number }
}

export interface Theme {
  title: string,
  logoPath: string,
  tags: string[],
  fields: Field<string>[]
}

const fields: Field<string>[] = [
  {
    name: "firstName",
    label: "First Name",
    type: "string",
    bounds: { lower: 1, upper: 1 },
    validator: (val: string) => {
     return val.length > 20;
    }
  }
]
```

Edit:

Also, if you want to constrain the type of `T` to just be one of `FieldType`, then you can do:

```
export interface Field<T extends FieldType> {
  name: string,
  label: string,
  type: FieldType,
  validator: (val: T) => boolean,
  bounds: { lower: number; upper: number }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reaching out. This way all the fields of theme are of type `string`. As i said before, `fields` can be of different types.

Comment: No problem! Just trying to help. So is it assumed that the value being passed into the validator is of the same type as `type`? Or is the validator's parameter type completely independent of the `type` property of the Field

Comment: `type` value is irrelevant to the type `validator` inputs. Actually `validator` parameter value could be `string`, `number` or `boolean`. That's why i'm trying to pass the type as a generator.

Comment: If that's the case, then you can forget about the generics all together and just declare the parameter `val` as type `FieldType`

Comment: The type `T` isn't used anywhere in your original example except as to declare the type of the parameter. Usually generics are used in more than one location to express that multiple values are of the same type.

Comment: `'string' | 'number' | 'boolean'`  is not the same as `string | number | boolean` and in case i follow your suggested route then i have to do type checking inside `validator` which doesn't sound much typescriptish  to me.